# Can I filter friends with FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm interested in rendering only a list of friends of a certain sex. I'm using the query below, but not having any luck:

`"SELECT name FROM user WHERE sex= $sex AND uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1= $fb_uid )"`

From what I understand, it should work because AT LEAST ONE of the constraints is indexable. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562/1228)

Answer (score 3):

Here are my thoughts:

1. Make sure that the user have the right permission, I guess it's [`read_stream`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)
2. Make sure the user you are matching is the logged in user (maybe using `me()` instead)
3. the `sex` field accepts only: `male` and `female`

Comment: This is a very good thing to check — unfortunately FQL calls (and Facebook API queries in general) will often fail silently if the right permissions haven't been secured already.

Comment: I tried the suggestions above, but my query still fails... perhaps, you can't filter by more than one condition?

Comment: Minding Dory's comment above, I caught the exception:

FacebookApiException Object ( [result:protected] => Array ( [error_code] => 602 [error_msg] => male is not a member of the user table. [request_args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => method [value] => fql.query ) [1] => Array ( [key] => query [value] => SELECT name FROM user WHERE sex=male AND uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=100000340657797 ) ) [2] => Array ( [key] => callback [value] => ) [3] => Array ( [key] => api_key [value] => 232695137903 ) [4] => Array ( [key] => ... it goes on.

I have no idea what this means.